# Jquery/js -- Slide between pages with separate urls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if it's possible to slide between pages (left to right, and vise versa) that have two different urls. I know a popular form of sliding is to use anchors to slide between, but I have a lot of different width %s and height %s in my code that is making it almost impossible to format correctly.

I was wondering if there is a way to do a left to right slide in Javascript/Jquery without using the anchor technique? Is this even possible? Like have two different urls (index.html and page2.html for instance) and slide between them.

Thank you!